# c# cloning object to new variable

Tags: c#

I have an class that I fill from database:

```
 // original data
var dbData = this.GetOriginalData(ID);
```

Then I want to create a new instance of the same object in which I can modify properties but keeping the original one as it is.

If I do:

```
var newData = dbData;
newData.Text = "Sample";
```

Then dbData.Text is also being altered.

> How can I create an instance of dbData without creating a new class and passing property by property or without using AutoMapper for example.

Comment: may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Json serializer to clone an object by creating a new object and copying all the properties using serialize/deserialize

```
public static T CloneJson<T>(this T source)
{            
    // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    // initialize inner objects individually
    // for example in default constructor some list property initialized with some values,
    // but in 'source' these items are cleaned -
    // without ObjectCreationHandling.Replace default constructor values will be added to result
    var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace};

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source), deserializeSettings);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon how would you call the function?

Comment: var newData = CloneJson<MyDataType>(dbData);   Where MyDataType is the class name of dbData

Comment: You'll also need to install Newtonsoft.Json from the Nuget Package Manager (right click your project, Manage Nuget Packages, search for NewtonSoft Json)